# Strange behavior of Mockito, a small portion of mock lost effect when ran in mvn test

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito

I'm working on merging 2 legacy projects, every junit test works fine in IDE(Intellij). But some error happens when I execute mvn test. From the error stacktrace, it looks like mock lost effects at some point somewhere. (In a total of about 700 tests, 6 failed).
A failuire example looks like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    private Child child;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeHandler handler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCall() {
        handler.call();
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeHandler {
    private Child child;

    public String call() {
        child.doA();
        child.doB();
        return "ccc";
    }
}
```

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void doB() {
        System.out.println("bbb");
    }
}
```

```
abstract class Parent {
    void doA() {
        System.out.println("aaa");
    }
}
```

This is just an example, and works as expected(real doA and doB are not invoked during test).
But in real codebase, doA got invoked unexpecttedly and some error happened.

What I have tried:

- run failed test class alone in mvn test -Dtest=xxx, failures disappeared.
- add `<forkMode>always</forkMode>` to surefile plugin configuration, failures disappeared.
- change doA() method in the Parent class from default to public, failures disappeared.

Does any of these behaviors looks familiar to your guys? How can I troubleshoot this problem so that it can just ran normally? I don't want to change source code just for unit test or change forkMode to always(too slow).

Comment: This question is asked in a really general form, IMO, so I don't see how I can provide a technical answer on this one. One thing that I think you should check is whether you don't have 2 different versions of Mockito clashing (one comes from the first project, and another one comes from the second project that you're about to merge).

Comment: @MarkBramnik sorry it's in a really general form because real codebase is company properties. And I'm not counting on receiving detailed solution, but some troubleshooting suggestion from experienced guys who might have encounted similar things in the past. And thanks for your "clashing" suggestion, it inspired me to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you add add "always to surefile plugin configuration", failures disappeared.

I think your problem is that you have tests which have side effects which influence your failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

It turns out some other test changed Classloader during test.

```
ClassLoader loader = xxx
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
```

Save the original classloader before that and restore it in the @After solved the problem.

```
public class XXXTest {
  private static ThreadLocal<ClassLoader> threadLocalClassloader = new ThreadLocal<>() ;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    threadLocalClassloader.set(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(threadLocalClassloader.get());
  }
}
```

This well explained

> add <forkMode>always</forkMode> to surefile plugin configuration, failures disappeared.

As for the reason of

> every junit test works fine in IDE(Intellij)

> change doA() method in the Parent class from default to public, failures disappeared.

It's too complicated and I can't explain why, maybe they're just coincidences...